# meteor requires npm install on each new machine

Tags: meteor, npm

I just cloned my meteor github repo to a new machine and now I have to npm install some packages again. I thought that they are part of the meteor app once I have them installed. (and I checked. they are in the node_modules folder and listed in the packages.json). Nonetheless, I get the error:

```
Can't find npm module 'react'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js witin the 'modules-runtime'package?
```

I am running meteor 1.3.1

Comment: Maybe some metadata is ignored in your repo, check the `.gitignore` file. Also run `meteor npm install` and see if it solves the issue if so, check for new files that were created and make that they getting into your commits.

Comment: yes that's probably the problem. i just checked and the node_modules is in .gitignore. but I thought that the packages get automatically added when they are listed in the package.json. That's at least what happens with atmosphere packages